# Civivolunteer:"view own assignments"?

Tags: civivolunteer

Is it possible to use the latest and greatest Civivolunteer to allow a user to see their own assignments on a dashboard or view?  Found this (https://github.com/aghstrategies/civivolunteer_views) but it appears lightly dated (still appreciative!)

Reasoning: people are not satisfied with just getting an email, we want to encourage them to login and review their assignments in their /user or ???page.